# zc.buildout stopped working: ImportError: No module named apport.fileutils

Tags: python, buildout

I've been using buildout for quite a while now without any issue, in fact I did yesterday without any problems.

But as today all my projects fail to buildout. I tried on two different Ubuntu workstations with the same result.

This is the error I get:

```
Initializing zc.buildout
Debug: Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 259, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.buildout
  File "/tmp/tmpNkVMXW/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 18, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.easy_install
  File "/tmp/tmpNkVMXW/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 59, in <module>
    pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('distribute')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
ImportError: No module named apport.fileutils

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 259, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.buildout
  File "/tmp/tmpNkVMXW/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 18, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.easy_install
  File "/tmp/tmpNkVMXW/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 59, in <module>
    pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('distribute')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'
```

It complains that there's no module named apport.fileutils .. but I get no exception when I run python and import it:

```
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

2.0.0 just got released. The old bootstrap.py is not compatible with 2.0.0 but downloads it by default. You can get the v2 bootstrap.py from [here](http://downloads.buildout.org/2/bootstrap.py), or use the code below if you want to stick with the old version.

```
python bootstrap.py -v 1.7.0
```

edit: older versions of v1 bootstrap.py don't allow version forcing. The up-to-date version [here](http://downloads.buildout.org/1/bootstrap.py) does.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I initially though I would upgrade buildout to 2.0 .. but it seems to breaks a lot of extensions so I'll stick with 1.7 for a while I think.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, thanks for your helpful answer! Relates also to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817138/zc-buildout-2-0-0-release-somehow-ends-up-breaking-plone-3-3-buildouts

Answer (score 0):

The question + answer is from 2013. I recently (2015) saw it happening again.

The problem is that ubuntu's `python-apport` package installs a `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py` file that overrides `sys.excepthook`. It makes sure python tracebacks are fed into ubuntu's "apport" error reporting mechanism.

That in itself is not a problem. But `bootstrap.py` restricts the python path, so that the hook cannot import `apport` anymore...

So if an error occurs during the bootstrap run, an exception is printed which then fails a second time because apport cannot be imported.

A solution could be to `sudo apt-get remove python-apport`. That's at least what we did on the server (where having apport makes no sense in any case).