# zc.buildout 2.0.0 release somehow ends up breaking Plone buildouts

Tags: plone, buildout

I am trying to run old Plone 3.3 buildout.cfg. In [versions] I pin down buildout as the following:

```
cat buildout.cfg|grep -i zc.buildout
zc.buildout = 1.4.3
```

However, for some reason bootstrap.py generated bin/buildout ends up using the latest 2.0.0 release:

```
cat bin/buildout|grep -i zc.buildout
  '/srv/plone/x/eggs/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.4.egg',
```

Which fails when trying to run bin/buildout:

```
      An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpjc_Zhu/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1808, in main
  File "/tmp/tmpjc_Zhu/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 455, in install
  File "/tmp/tmpjc_Zhu/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 888, in _maybe_upgrade
  File "/tmp/tmpjc_Zhu/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 759, in install
  File "/tmp/tmpjc_Zhu/zc.buildout-2.0.0-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 578, in install
TypeError: get_dist() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
*********************************************
Overwriting versions.cfg
```

How to make buildout to bootstrap itself as 1.4.3 (compatible version)?

This concerns only fresh runs of this buildout.cfg. On my old system which uses zc.buildout 1.4.3 already I cannot repeat the problem.

Comment: Relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801416/zc-buildout-stopped-working-importerror-no-module-named-apport-fileutils

Comment: btw: is there a difference between the 'buildout' and the 'zc.buildout' tag?

Comment: I've made a blog post that lists the common problem: http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2013/02/12/prevent-buildout-problems.html . @mikko-ohtamaa's answer is right: pick a fresh 1.x bootstrap.

Comment: `buildout` and `zc.buildout` tag: no real difference, except that `buildout` is used way more often. So I personally try to edit tags so that they use `buildout`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to use this `bootstrap.py`:

```
  http://downloads.buildout.org/1/bootstrap.py
```

This one is **not** good:

```
  http://svn.zope.org/repos/main/zc.buildout/trunk/bootstrap/bootstrap.py
```

More details here:

https://github.com/miohtama/senorita.plonetool/commit/75f54c818801e9eeb10c38962e5ccc58f8b2f031

Comment: Or you can use `python bootstrap.py -v 1.7.0` to determine what version is installed.

Comment: +1 for both of you for helpful infos :) Mikko you might accept your answer, or is there some timegap which has to pass before SO allows you to do that?